# What is the regex for “Any positive integer, excluding 0”

Tags: javascript, regex, integer

There is already an other post for this but i can't comment on it.
Sorry for that.

I used

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^[1-9]\d*$'); 
var result = fieldValue.search(pattern);
```

but i get a "-1" if I put 12

It allows me just number from 1 to 9 and no more.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Please tag the language, I assume this is JavaScript, is that correct?

Comment: Use regex literal please. You need to escape ``\`` if you use constructor with string literal.

Comment: Ah ok nhahtdh :) that was y mistake.. :(

Comment: Yes zzzzBov it's javascript

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew why did you mark my question as duplicate with this question? I didn't ask for why it needs to be double escape but what is the regex of a positive number, someone answer that I needed to escape but when I asked my question in 2015 I didn't know that obviously ;) Your link help to understand the mistake I made in the past but doesn't reply directly to the question asked. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming the language is JavaScript, you need to escape the backslash character within a string for it to have a value of backslash:

`'\d'` is a string with a value of `d`
`'\\d'` is a string with a value of `\d`

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^[1-9]\\d*$');
```

JavaScript also has regular expression literals, which avoid the need for additional escape characters:

```
var pattern = /^[1-9]\d*$/;
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) 
I will remember know, just started with javascript few weeks ago.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to extend this to allow for positive integers with leading zeros, you could do this:

```
var pattern = /^\d*[1-9]+\d*$/
```

This will allow 001 as a valid input (which it is), while not allowing 000 (which is not non zero).